# How to change citation output to superscript in Word - Vancouver referencing

Tags: microsoft-word

I am using the [Vancouver.xls](https://github.com/mback2k/bibword-styles/blob/master/Vancouver.xsl) reference style in my Word 16. It has been great so far but there is one major issue I am currently facing. My school recommendation for the in-text citations stated that the reference number should be without a bracket and should be in superscript, however, the default output of the Vancouver.xls is having the brackets and is not in superscript.
How can I change the output to automatically remove the brackets and change it to superscript each time I cite a reference in my Word document?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using
[Vancouver.xsl](https://github.com/mback2k/bibword-styles/blob/master/Vancouver.xsl),
but here are two guesses on how to change it.
I suggest that you apply them one-by-one, taking a backup at
each step.
Let me know if any of them works.

**Superscript setting**

Find the following two lines:

```
<!-- Formatting options. Currently only 's' is supported for printing the ordinal part in superscript. -->
<xsl:param name="options"/>
```

Change the second line so that it looks like:

```
<xsl:param name="options" select="s">
```

**Remove the brackets**

Find the following two lines:

```
  <openbracket>(</openbracket>
  <closebracket>)</closebracket>
```

and erase the brackets between the tags:

```
  <openbracket></openbracket>
  <closebracket></closebracket>
```

Comment: Alright, let me try this first. Thank you very much Harry

Comment: The brackets were removed, however, the superscript have not worked. What else can I try?

Comment: This was documented as *the* method for doing superscript, even as said the comment above it. I can't help if it doesn't work anymore. Try maybe to find the author and ask him.

Comment: Alright, thank you for your help.